# Get size of relation |R|

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Task:

> If |A| = 30 and equivalence R on A induces three partitions $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$
>   and |$A_1$| = |$A_2$| = |$A_3$|, what is |R|?

My solution is $|R| = 300$.
I know that count of elements in partitions is $10$ and then every pair need to be connected with other $9$ pairs and plus 10 because of maintaining reflexivity, so it is $3 * (10 * 9 + 10)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct except for a small error in terminology: $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$ are not partitions. The actual partition is the set $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$; the sets $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$ are the parts or pieces of the partition.

Comment: Or equivalence classes...

Comment: @MLN96: My pleasure.